# Using golang's defer in a separate method

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I'm using the golang RabbitMQ library in a project, and I have a `Connect` function in a separate package. I'm calling Connect, in my `main` function, however because I connect to RabbitMQ in a separate function, the `defer conn.Close()` function is called, which closes the connection within the Connect function. Which makes perfect sense, but that begs the question, where then, do I call `conn.Close()`?

```
package drivers

import (

    // Core
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    // Third party
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

type Queue struct {
    Channel *amqp.Channel
}

func NewQueue() *Queue {
    return &Queue{}
}

// Queue interface
type IQueue interface {
    Connect(args ...interface{})
    Publish(queue string, payload []byte) error
    Listen(queue string) (<-chan amqp.Delivery, error)
    Declare(queue string) (amqp.Queue, error)
}

// Connect - Connects to RabbitMQ
func (queue *Queue) Connect(args ...interface{}) {

    var uri string

    if args == nil {

        // Get from env vars
        uri = os.Getenv("RABBIT_MQ_URI")

        if uri == "" {
            log.Panic("No uri for queue given")
        }
    } else {
        uri = args[0].(string)
    }

    // Make max 5 connection attempts, with a 1 second timeout
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {

        log.Println("Connecting to:", uri)

        // If connection is successful, return new instance
        conn, err := amqp.Dial(uri)
        defer conn.Close()

        if err == nil {
            log.Println("Successfully connected to queue!")
            channel, _ := conn.Channel()
            queue.Channel = channel
            return
        }

        log.Println("Failed to connect to queue, retrying...", err)

        // Wait 1 second
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

// Declare a new queue
func (queue *Queue) Declare(queueName string) (amqp.Queue, error) {
    return queue.Channel.QueueDeclare(
        queueName,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
}

// Publish a message
func (queue *Queue) Publish(queueName string, payload []byte) error {
    return queue.Channel.Publish(
        "",
        queueName,
        false,
        false,
        amqp.Publishing{
            DeliveryMode: amqp.Persistent,
            ContentType:  "application/json",
            Body:         payload,
        },
    )
}

// Listen for a new message
func (queue *Queue) Listen(queueName string) (<-chan amqp.Delivery, error) {
    return queue.Channel.Consume(
        queueName,
        "",
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        nil,
    )
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I'm calling `defer conn.Close()` after making a connection, however, this immediately closes the connection again.

Here's a Go Playground spoofing what I'm talking about... https://play.golang.org/p/5cz2D4gDgn

Comment: The obvious answer is you call Close when you're done with the connection; where that is in your code is up to you. If `Queue` is a proxy for the connection, why not expose a Close method there?

Comment: You're absolutely right! That is kinda obvious now you've pointed it out. I've exposed the channel and connection properties and am now calling defer on those in my main function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to call `conn.Close()` from elsewhere.  This might just be me, but I think it's kinda odd that you wouldn't expose the connection elsewhere, i.e. as a field in `Queue`.  Exposing the ability to close the connection from the Queue would solve this and give you more flexibility.

So this:

```
type Queue struct {
    // your original fields
    Conn amqp.Connection
}

// Somewhere else
queue.Conn.Close()
```

You're other option is connecting, then doing all the actions you want with that connection, then closing.  I'm thinking something like:

```
func action(conn amqp.Connection, args ...interface{}) (<-chan bool) {
    done := make(chan bool)
    go func(amqpConn amqp.Connection, dChan chan bool){
        // Do what you want with the connection
        dChan <- true
    }(conn, done)
    return done
}

func (queue *Queue) Connect(args ...interface{}) {
     // your connection code
     doneChans := make([](chan bool), 5)
     for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {
          conn, err := amqp.Dial(uri)
          defer conn.Close()
          if err != nil {
              // handle error
          }
          done := action(conn)
     }
     // This for loop will block until the 5 action calls are done
     for j := range doneChans {
         isFinish := <-doneChans[j]
         if !isFinish {
             // handle bad state
         }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to have `Connect` return `conn`, and call `defer conn.Close()` in the caller.

```
package driver

// imports, etc

func (queue *Queue) Connect(args ...interface{}) amqp.Connection, error {
    // ...

    conn, err := amqp.Dial(uri)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // ...

    return conn, nil
}
```

Then in another package:

```
package stuff

// imports, etc

func doStuff() {
    queue = driver.NewQueue()

    conn, err := queue.Connect(args...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("oh no! %v!", err)
    }

    defer conn.Close()

    // Do stuff
}
```